# Accounting for /proc/net/dev reported traffic

Tags: networking, monitoring, proc, netstat, traffic

I noticed that according to /proc/net/dev I am constantly receiving around 6Kb/s on my wireless usb interface. But I can't account for anything even close to that with the individual connections that I get with iptraf, iftop, and nethogs. Investigations with netstat, lsof, and tcpdump didn't help either.

So, what else could contribute to /proc/net/dev values? I can speculate that, while only IP based traffic is reported by the applications I mentioned, /proc/net/dev probably accounts for other link-layer/internet-layer stuff too (arp? icmp? wireless management stuff?). Or maybe other transport/application protocols. Can anyone confirm this?

How else would you proceed to find out: through what sockets are the 6Kb/s coming through? What processes are receiving the traffic?

---

[EDIT]

The 2 consistent results across all the tools:

1. the totals of Rx are around a few Kb/s

   - confirmed with /proc/net/dev, dstat, bmw-ng, cbm, iptraf, ifstat, gnome-system-monitor
2. no connection/packet stream justifies that

   - confirmed with netstat, tcpdump, iftop, nethogs, iptraf

All of this with a Netgear WDNA 4100 wireless usb adapter using a custom driver from some git (the only way I got it to work). I asked the devs about it [here](https://github.com/ashaffer/rt3573sta/issues/9).

This might be malware, but I suspect the driver is simply reporting wrong totals. Nevertheless, I cannot explain what's going on for sure.

Comment: Can you show exactly what you're talking about? How did you determine this number?

Comment: @slm: I didn't calculate directly from /proc/net/dev, I relied on tools that get their data there and do the calculation. The exact number is not important, but if I `watch -n 0.2 'cat /proc/net/dev'`, I see the byte total constantly increasing. This is consistent with results from gnome-system-monitor, iptraf's "general interface statistics", bwm-ng, etc.

Comment: `tcpdump -n -i wlan0` (or whatever the device is called) shows *no* traffic?

Comment: @derobert: it does, but not nearly enough to cover the 6Kb/s total I get from several sources

Comment: I have a similar situation where `enp1s0` apparently has Gbps of constant traffic.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with applications that are using up network bandwidth the best tool I've come across for tying back utilization to specific apps has got to be `nethogs`.

You can use `ip link show` or `netstat -i` to find out your network interface names.

```
$ netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
em1       1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
lo       65536    81375      0      0 0         81375      0      0      0 LRU
virbr0    1500        0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 BMU
wlp3s0    1500  2264942      0      0 0       2376236      0      0      0 BMRU
```

My wireless on my Fedora 19 laptop is `wlp3s0`, so we tell `nethogs` to watch that:

```
$ sudo nethogs wlp3s0
```

[image: ss #1]

As you let `nethogs` run it will start to show you the applications that are consuming your network bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks, but I've been through that and it doesn't add up here. In fact, the total I get in nethogs and other tools is mostly at 0.000, while /proc/net/dev based calculations show a few thousand bytes coming in every second through my wireless usb adapter. BTW, this is not the case is another machine with a very similar installation but which is plugged through Ethernet. That's why I speculated some low level protocol msgs (for some wireless link management or sth) could be contributing to /proc/net/dev totals, although not participating in open socket totals. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ricab - if there isn't an app pulling the data directly then I'd check with tcpdump. You should be able to determine the nature of the packets flowing in/out. I'd be a little suspicious at this point, possible malware. I was looking at my wireless and there doesn't appear to be 6Kb/s levels of traffic for wireless network "plumbing" type of traffic. It could be something hammering your IP that might be the cause too.

Comment: Tcpdump doesn't help either. The 2 consistent results across all the tools: 1) the totals of Rx are around a few Kb; 2) no connection/packet stream justifies that. All of this with a Netgear WDNA 4100 wireless usb adapter using a custom driver from [some git](https://github.com/ashaffer/rt3573sta) (the only way I got it to work). This might be malware, but I suspect the driver is simply reporting wrong totals. Nevertheless, I cannot explain what's going on for sure. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @ricab - sounds suspicious to me. Check to see if any malware installed modified versions of `tcpdump`, modified versions could mask any actual traffic.

Comment: Nope, I verified my tcpdump with `debsums` and, manually, against [the web listed md5](http://tinyurl.com/qe4rodx) and it's the original. Besides, this malware would have to have installed modified versions of  `netstat`, `iftop`, `nethogs`, and `iptraf` as well to mask the traffic there. Unless the change was in a shared lib, but I just verified all libs I got with `ldd /usr/sbin/tcpdump` (from deb packages `libssl1.0.0` `libpcap0.8` `libc6` `zlib1g`). So I can't see it as being due to malware, except if it was in the wifi driver itself, which I doubt (it's public code). But thanks any case