# Send/Receive bandwidth monitor per application?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm looking for a tool that can monitor my system and create some summary how many data was sent or received by each application/process. Is something like this? I found nethogs but he shows only real time bandwidth usage.

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114803/accounting-for-proc-net-dev-reported-traffic/114887#114887

Comment: Yeah only related i have slightly different use case i want stats per process not per entire device.

Comment: `nethogs` was the only app I found that would show you bandwidth consumption by a given app. The related Q I linked shows this.